# Connection Firebase Firestore to laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, laravel-5.8

I have installed **laravel 5.8** and firebase project with **firestore** database.

```
 "name": "laravel/framework",
 "version": "v5.8.36",
```

Firestore database connected to android app. App fetches data good from Firestore. Than I want to create admin panel with laravel for android app and want to integrate laravel with that database.But can not do this.

What I did:

1. installed php7.2
2. installed laravel 5.8.*
3. added php extension gRPC*
4. Added gRPC as a Composer dependency `composer require "grpc/grpc:^v1.1.0"` in laravel project
5. installed `composer require google/cloud-firestore`
6. Generated Firebase Admin SDK json file and saved into storage folder in laravel
7. Added this variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/storage/files/progressive-yooung-team-firebase-adminsdk-ax7wi-d2a85ecabc.json` (json file which generated firebase admin SDK) in .env file of laravel
8. installed `composer require kreait/firebase-php ^4.35`
9. Created Controller 'VarController' code:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;


   class VarController extends Controller
   {
       public function index()
       {
           print_r("Output: 1");
           $factory = new Factory();
           print_r("Output: 2");
           $firestore = $factory->createFirestore();
           print_r("Output: 3");
           $database = $firestore->database();

           $userRef =  $database->collection('users');
           $snapshot = $userRef->document('Hus')->snapshot();

           if($snapshot->exists()) {
               printf('Document data:' . PHP_EOL);
               print_r($snapshot->data());

           }
           print_r("Output: 4");
       }
   }
   ```

Problem is, It does not fetch data from firestore **document 'Hus'** and its data exists:

> users > Hus > name: "Husniddin"

I put `print_r("Output: 1")`, Output: 2, etc... in order to know where is problem. On screen I see only: Output: 1 Output: 2.

Answer (score 2):

Also don't forget to import these .

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use \Kreait\Firebase\Database;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
```

After that , call the `ServiceAccount()` inside your function.

```
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/Firebase.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
$firestore = new FirestoreClient([
            'projectId' => 'Your project name',
        ]);
        $collectionReference = $firestore->collection('users');

$documentReference = $collectionReference->document('Search element from document');
        $snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();
```

Comment: @faroq, Unfortunately this code also do not work after `withServiceAccount()` method no code work, for example I put after that code print:"print_r('Output: 3')" but it does not show.

Answer (score 0):

change 
`$snapshot = $userRef->document('Hus')->snapshot();`

to 
`$snapshot = $userRef->document('Hus')->documents();`